# Pandas str slice in combination with Pandas str index

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a `Dataframe` containing a single column with a list of file names. I want to find all rows in the `Dataframe` that their value has a prefix from a set of know prefixes.

I know I can run a simple `for` loop, but I want to run in a `Dataframe` to check speeds and run benchmarks - it's also a nice exercise.

What I had in mind is combining `str.slice` with `str.index` but I can't get it to work. This is what I have in mind:

```
import pandas as pd

file_prefixes = {...}
file_df = pd.Dataframe(list_of_file_names)

file_df.loc[file_df.file.str.slice(start=0, stop=upload_df.file.str.index('/')-1).isin(file_prefixes), :] # this doesn't work as the index returns a dataframe
```

My hope is that said code will return all rows that the value there starts with a file prefix from the list above.

In summary, I would like help with 2 things:

1. Combining `slice` and `index`
2. Thoughts about better ways to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will use `startswith`

```
file_df.loc[file_df.file.str.startswith(tuple(file_prefixes)), :]
```